# Smooth open sans everywhere, but not on my website?

Tags: css, fonts, typekit

I keep seeing the font Open Sans everywhere, and it's really smooth most of the time, even in Chrome. But when I add open sans from adobe typekit or google fonts to my website, it's just jagged and boring. I have googled A LOT and I can't seem to find any working solution at all.

If anyone has some good information on this, it would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: A link or screenshot please. Its really hard to help without seeing what's wrong.

Comment: Code, please. Code needed to reproduce the problem. A link or a screenshort are nice extra, but not a real description.

Answer (score -1):

It's better for you by using font face rather than adobe type kit. Download them on http://www.fontsquirrel.com/

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'open_sansregular';
    src: url('OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('OpenSans-Regular-webfont.svg#open_sansregular') format('svg'),
         url('OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('OpenSans-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```